# http to https redirection and vice versa

Tags: deployment, configuration

I am facing a wired problem, if I deploy my website on production server and let say it is accessible as www.sampledomain.com

One of the major issues that we are facing after exposing it on public internet is that httpRedirection 301 is not working.

We have the following page that should only be accessible over https [we have a valid SSL certificate installed and configured on the website], we have set the flag RequiresSSL to true for one of the page in the website

http://sampledomain.com/feedback

Hence when this page is requested over http, server send the http 301 status code with but does not update the location field in the response header. Below are the request and response header captured via fiddler.

Request Header

```
GET http://sampledomain.com/feedback  HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: sampledomain.com
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=1qhnx44cyjev5n4dkvdad31l;.ASPXAUTH=FF155AF2A8698A8AC1AB36639BB3C0BF4C4CABCB8FEA1982A02103A137577F5FC9432578B74E60E0F2999E3BCD33A7FDBE61CABAF3B20FC884A13D56BFCB0810202D58C0718D7987F74F26A8288F1276F2AD0046CAA2132E56D35299482EC1B6BCACC114BDB3496AA5BA5DBFCAA05DF65C0D6E406A5B36135079FF7F9C5A34B3
```

Response Header

```
HTTP/1.1 301 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 208
Date: Wed, 05 Dec 2012 06:35:39 GMT
Location: http://sampledomain.com/feedback  
Server: PSA's Webserver

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://sampledomain.com/feedback  ">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Here you see that server is sending the same url back in the Location field, hence the browser gets trapped into infinite loop and page is not loaded.

If i request the page over https protocol, everything works fine.
https://sampledomain.com/feedback

Also the automatic http redirection works fine if we access the website from with the network, means when we are not going through the internet and access the website through the corporate network.

would really appreciate help in resolving this issue

Thanks & Regards

Gaurav

Comment: Just so we're clear on a couple of things: we're talking about asp.net mvc here, right? If so, are we talking about `RequireHttps` (standard asp.net tag) or `RequiresSsl` (asp.net futures, which seems severely outdated)? Is this running on IIS? Is everything configured to expose port 443 to the outside world? ...

Comment: Its asp.net webforms which uses routing. Yes the application is running on IIS 7.5 and https binding is configured on port 443. Also its a CMS based system where we have a flag on page object called RequiresSSL, if its set to true, page manager switches the protocol from http to https [when a secured page is accessed over http].